# Error while parsing json file with objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

When I'm parsing single object , it's not getting error. after append second object to JSON file, its giving error. what's wrong with my file.
this is my json file after adding second object:

```
{
"_id":1,
"cid":3067,
"name":"Tech Mahindra",
"type":["Information Technology and Services"],
"empSize":99704,
"empSizeInfo":[
        {
            "on":1507141800,
            "size":99704
        }
    ],
"domain":"http://www.techmahindra.com/theme/DAVID.html",
"loc":{
    "ct":"Maharashtra",
    "cy":"in",
    "pCode":"411004"
},
"followers":370803,
"ctdOn":1507141800,
"status":0,
"updtdOn":1507141800,
"cmptd":1}
```

and my second object is:

```
{
"_id":2,
"cid":3178,
"name":"JLL",
"type":["Commercial Real Estate"],
"empSize":45147,
"empSizeInfo":[
        {
            "on":1500229800,
            "size":45147
        }
    ],
"domain":"http://www.jll.com",
"followers":472853,
"ctdOn":1500229800,
"status":0,
"loc":{
    "ct":"Haryana",
    "cy":"in",
    "pCode":"122002"
},
"cmptd":1}
```

It's getting error after adding second document nodejs JSON.parse().
my file contains multiple objects.
This is my nodejs code:

```
const fs= require("fs")
//const jsonfile= require("jsonfile")
//const bulkindex= require("./bulkindex.js")
const test= function(){
fs.readFile("a.json",'utf-8',function(err,data){
    if(err) throw err;
    data1=JSON.parse(data) // getting error here
    //bulkindex.bulkIndex("mathced","profiles",data1);
    console.log(data1)
});
//console.log(jsonfile.readFileSync("a.json"))
}
test()
```

and this is the error:

```
undefined:25
{
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at Object.parse (native)
at /home/sys2047/Desktop/EmailPrediction/Elastic Search/test.js:7:14
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

How can  I parse this json file. ?

Comment: you have to append with a comma ,

Comment: can you show the resultant json

Comment: then it will become [object,object]. but it's not i need. i need to parse this json file. without editing anything. my json file contains thousands of objects.

Comment: you probably have to set the two objects in an array.. try validating json in sites like http://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: getting parse error, after 1st document . in jsoneditoronline.org

Comment: do you have wrapping Array initializers and separating commas? you can't just concat objects...

Comment: No. I got this json from mongo export command

Comment: if you have the commas, all you need to do is add the array blocks: `data1=JSON.parse("["+data+"]")`

Comment: hm. my objects not separated with commas. what can i do now?

Comment: something _like_ `data1=JSON.parse("["+data.replace(/\}\{/g, "},{")+"]");`, matched to your object's "toe to head", might need a line break, space, etc...

Comment: just make your json array valid...in order to see if your json is parsable or not ..it can be validated on this [site] (https://jsonformatter.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json array has format of

[ json 1 , json 2]

what you are doing is json1 concated to json 2...

try adding "[" & "]" before parsing

have a look at this [array of json](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

all parasable Json should be valid..you can [validate Online too](https://jsonformatter.org/)
making your data look something like this will help you parse

```
 [{
"_id":1,
"cid":3067,
"name":"Tech Mahindra",
"type":["Information Technology and Services"],
"empSize":99704,
"empSizeInfo":[
        {
            "on":1507141800,
            "size":99704
        }
    ],
"domain":"http://www.techmahindra.com/theme/DAVID.html",
"loc":{
    "ct":"Maharashtra",
    "cy":"in",
    "pCode":"411004"
},
"followers":370803,
"ctdOn":1507141800,
"status":0,
"updtdOn":1507141800,
"cmptd":1} ,

{
"_id":2,
"cid":3178,
"name":"JLL",
"type":["Commercial Real Estate"],
"empSize":45147,
"empSizeInfo":[
        {
            "on":1500229800,
            "size":45147
        }
    ],
"domain":"http://www.jll.com",
"followers":472853,
"ctdOn":1500229800,
"status":0,
"loc":{
    "ct":"Haryana",
    "cy":"in",
    "pCode":"122002"
},
"cmptd":1}
]
```

Comment: I just  changed utf8 from utf-8. but still getting same error.

Comment: yes. but how to change  my json format now? i had lots of objects in this format

Comment: do  some manipulations...at the time or either reading or writing the file...for e.g. while writing add comma before appending...& while reading add a [ & ]